# How to stop console output

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus

I have a script and the output appears on the console and it should be only in the output file , this is the sql query header from the script :

```
sqlplus -s ${connString} <<EOF &

SET HEADING OFF FEEDBACK OFF ECHO OFF PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 1024
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
SPOOL $logdir/Report_$YYYYMMDD.txt
```

sql query

```
SPOOL OFF
EOF
```

Comment: I think you might be after [`set termout off`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-1DC0410D-E0C5-43D1-82A1-8178D0B1EC1C.htm#SUTIL1518)

Comment: set termout off did not work but J. Schübel answer works like a charm , thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect `sqlplus`'s output to a file. You can do this by adding `>>filename.log` to your first line like so:

```
sqlplus -s ${connString}  <<EOF >filename.log
```

The `&` in your first line is a syntax error.

If you only need one output file, you don't need `spool` so your script would look like this:

```
OUTFILE="Report_$(date '+%Y%m%d').txt"
sqlplus -s ${connString} <<EOF >|"$OUTFILE"

SET HEADING OFF FEEDBACK OFF ECHO OFF PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 1024
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE

--query

EOF
```